# fwrite() not writing entire ppm file

Tags: c

So, I'm struggling with a homework which asks me to anti-alias a photo. But that's not the point of my question. The files are .ppm [ppm format](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html). I read it, using `fread` (it's color so I need to read rgb).

```
fread(tmp, 3 * sizeof(char), maxWidth * maxHeight, f)
```

where

```
tmp = (char *)malloc(width * height * 3 * sizeof(char));
```

I cast the tmp to short int (I need to do some work on the resulting matrix):

```
for(i=0; i < width * height; i++){
    values[i] = (short int)tmp[i];
}
```

values is defined as short int:

```
values =  (short int*) malloc(width * height * sizeof(short int));
```

The thing is that I just wanted to make a test. Read the image, transform it to `int`, transform it back to char, write the image. In this stage, only 1/4 of the image is written and I don't know why. I read the documentation for `fwrite`, but I cannot find out what I am doing wrong. Transform the image back (tmp2 allocated as img):

```
for(i=0; i < width * height; i++){
    tmp2[i] = (char)values[i];
}

fwrite(tmp2, 3 * sizeof(char), width * height, g);
```

Am I using fwrite correctly? Maybe someone struggled with this too and knows how to answer.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are working with c++? I believe Java handles file streams in a much better way.

Comment: @CrakC: That would be a pretty poor reason to translate the entire program, or to violate the requirements of the homework.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Since when can `fread` and `fwrite` not be used to work with text files?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg if it's P6 format, it's binary.

Comment: The algorithm works for P5 format (black and white - reading only size of char, not 3*sizeof(char)).

Comment: You've only filled in `width * height` bytes in `tmp2`, but you're writing `3 * width * height` bytes out from it.

Comment: @AlanStokes yes, but i can't go to 3 * width * height. because values have only width * height space.

Comment: Post more of the code.  Are you checking the value returned from both `fread()` and `fwrite()`?  And as @AlanStokes noted, you can't use a buffer of size N as a source for 3*N bytes.

Comment: @AlanStokes was right. I solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `short int` is 16 bits, or two bytes. In:

```
for(i=0; i < width * height; i++){
    values[i] = (short int)tmp[i];
}
```

you are only copying 2/3rd of the image data (and there is more wrong as each byte gets copied twice: `i` is incremented with 1 byte and the cast takes two bytes, one of which was copied already). Then in:

```
for(i=0; i < width * height; i++){
    tmp2[i] = (char)values[i];
}
```

you are copying only half of `values` (the first byte of each short), or 1/3rd of the image. Then in:

```
fwrite(tmp2, 3 * sizeof(char), width * height, g);
```

you are writing the correct mount of bytes, but the file contains only 1/3rd of the image (and a lot of garbage or zeroes).

I leave fixing this to you.

Comment: Oh, i see. Thank you! :)